# Can a custom attribute query the value of the property it's attached to?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, properties

Example:

```
[OnlyShowIfValueIsNonZero]
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

In the code for `OnlyShowIfValueIsNonZero`, I need to be able to query the value of `Foo`. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Presumably your code that uses this attribute has access to the class type and an instance. If it does then it becomes a question of getting a property value from an instance and `Type`, which has been answered many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attribute is not aware of the member it is assigned to, and for an attribute an instance will only be created if you access it via reflection. You cannot let an attribute interact with code directly - there are some frameworks like PostSharp though that inject code at compile time using attributes.

You can however from reflection supply the member it is assigned to, and since you already need the member to access its attributes, you could create a method in that attribute that accepts the member as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're starting to get into the world of aspect orientated programming here. Many AOP frameworks provide extensibility points to define your own custom aspects - which is what I think would suit you.

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) is a very popular AOP framework for .NET

Answer (score 0):

maybe , it is like this. 
and for example , T is your class...

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in (typeof(T)).GetProperties()){
    foreach (object attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if ( attribute is OnlyShowIfValueIsNonZero )
        {
           ......
        }
    }
}
```